# tableView re-using indexPath after 10 cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is a follow-up to my earlier question. I changed the code to employ non-reusable cells, thinking that somehow cell re-use was duplicating my timers. It still happens. I did an NSLog of the tableView Cells and from the listing you can see that the indexPath starts to repeat after 10 or 11 cells. Why would this be? You can also see that the app entered background mode at row 10 because the message "Saved all of the BNR Items" appears. I swear I did not hit the Home button. But that is what seems to be the cause of the tableView cell re-use: the restoration code isn't working properly, so the indexPath reset to 0.

New code:

```
    #pragma mark -tableView

// **** changelog 10/2/2015 ***************************************
// alternates blue and white rows

- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
  willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell
forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2
    ? [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.0 green: 0.3 blue: 1.0 alpha: 0.3]
    : [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
// *********************************************************************
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableview{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[NRCItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 60.0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"NRCItemCell"];
    // Get a new or recycled cell
    //NRCItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NRCItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.timerItem.cell = cell;
    [self handleTimer];
    NSLog(@"cell for row at index %@ is %@", indexPath, cell);
    return cell;
}

    2015-10-11 12:41:06.398 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740b9f20>
2015-10-11 12:41:06.409 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d52e340; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'panda'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022e6c0>>
2015-10-11 12:41:16.837 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702a5580>
2015-10-11 12:41:16.840 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d5353a0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'cub'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17022fb00>>
2015-10-11 12:41:29.777 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740bb660>
2015-10-11 12:41:29.780 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000010016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d63c0d0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'bob'; layer = <CALayer: 0x1742311c0>>
2015-10-11 12:41:44.201 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702a8f40>
2015-10-11 12:41:44.204 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d536810; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'carol'; layer = <CALayer: 0x170224e20>>
2015-10-11 12:41:55.906 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702aae00>
2015-10-11 12:41:55.909 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000020016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d639ec0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Ted'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422d180>>
2015-10-11 12:42:08.346 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740be000>
2015-10-11 12:42:08.349 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000028016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d50c230; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Alice'; layer = <CALayer: 0x170230120>>
2015-10-11 12:42:20.786 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702a8d60>
2015-10-11 12:42:20.789 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000030016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d51ab40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'John'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17003aa40>>
2015-10-11 12:42:32.058 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702aac80>
2015-10-11 12:42:32.061 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000038016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 7} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d63ea20; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Mary'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422c9e0>>
2015-10-11 12:42:49.917 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740be420>
2015-10-11 12:42:49.920 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000040016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 8} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d63f660; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'sue'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17403aba0>>
2015-10-11 12:43:03.588 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740be840>
2015-10-11 12:43:03.590 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000048016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 9} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d636d40; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Joan'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422cce0>>
2015-10-11 12:43:24.583 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1702a8ee0>
2015-10-11 12:43:24.586 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000050016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 10} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d642ad0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'sarah'; layer = <CALayer: 0x174230740>>
2015-10-11 12:43:45.782 timeLogger[1447:760103] Saved all of the BNRItems
2015-10-11 12:44:15.109 timeLogger[1447:760103] This was returned from detailViewController <NRCtimerItem: 0x1740b9fe0>
2015-10-11 12:44:15.114 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000058016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d646c60; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Pete'; layer = <CALayer: 0x174230fc0>>
2015-10-11 12:44:17.629 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000058016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 11} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d642fd0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Joan'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422df00>>
2015-10-11 12:44:19.520 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d622a20; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Joan'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422e7c0>>
2015-10-11 12:44:30.359 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d53b4f0; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Joan'; layer = <CALayer: 0x17003a800>>
2015-10-11 12:44:30.943 timeLogger[1447:760103] cell for row at index <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000050016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 10} is <UITableViewCell: 0x14d509080; frame = (0 0; 320 44); text = 'Joan'; layer = <CALayer: 0x170232ca0>>
```

Comment: What's wrong with cell-reuse? By turning it off you are just working around an issue rather than just fixing the problem. Why not just give each cell it's own timer?

Comment: Since it seems you are not reusing cells, maybe the explanation is just that iOS may call cellForRowAtIndexPath more than once for the same cell.  I don't know why I see "Joan" at index 9, then 0 and 10.  In this callback you should determine your "name" from the indexPath and assign your text.  I don't know what you are trying to do with a timer, but you can't assume that cellForRowAtIndexPath will only get called once.

Comment: It looks like you need to rethink your app structure. A cell is just a view on some data. There should be nothing in the cell that prevents it being reused and there should be nothing that is affected if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called 0 or 100 times for a given cell. Also, just because you have disabled reuse doesn't mean that the tableview won't request the cell for a row as required (ie scrolling) - it doesn't keep a reference for offscreen cells as it assumes that you are doing things properly and are reusing cells

Comment: Also you haven't explained exactly what your app is doing, but if you are displaying multiple timers the general approach is to store an array of timer "ticks", have a single NSTimer and update the appropriate tick counts each time it triggers. Updating a property (`self.timeritem.cell`) in `cellForRowAtIndexpath` makes little sense since you don't know the order in which this method will be called